# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DjangoFilterBackend'

Tags: django, django-filter

I am using django-filter but i get following error that  'module' object has no attribute 'DjangoFilterBackend'
I am sending my code below:

**Model.py**

```
    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class searchModel(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    image    = models.ImageField(upload_to='Image/')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %  self.email
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import searchModel

class searchserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model=searchModel
        fields=('email','password','image')
```

**Views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import searchModel
from .serializers import searchserializer
#from django_filters.rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import filters

class searchView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=searchModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = searchserializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_fields = ('email')
    ordering = ('email')
```

Comment: If you only want to filter by email, you can overwrite get_queryset in your searchView.

Answer (score 7):

Using the suggested import from the [rest framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends), you would do:

```
import django_filters.rest_framework

class searchView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class searchView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
```

Comment: "Not working" is not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you 
Check the below code :

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import filters

class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
  serializer_class = TaskSerializers
  filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
```

Comment: from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import searchModel
from .serializers import searchserializer
#from django_filters.rest_framework import filters
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import filters

class searchView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=searchModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = searchserializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields = ('email')
    ordering = ('email')

Answer (score 0):

Using this import will do:

```
import django_filters.rest_framework
filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Same - the reason is that FilterSet is part of django_filters, not rest_framekwork, so:

...

## remove the "from rest_framework import filters" line

...
from django_filters import FilterSet, AllValuesFilter, DateTimeFilter, NumberFilter